# Javascript, cut string to under length, but only at specific spots

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

Let's say I have a long string, each part following this format: `<@some numbers>`
And I also have a character limit. I want it to cut the string only at the spaces but have it under the character limit I set.

Example Input:

```
Input: <@756307474931515432> <@123891849950781999> <@935718581892734987> <@589058297589273488>
Character Limit: 54
```

Instead of cutting it right at the 54'th character, cut it in the space in-between.

```
Incorrect: <@756307474931515432> <@123891849950781999> <@93571858
Correct: <@756307474931515432> <@123891849950781999>
```

A possibility of achieving what I want would to be to split the string every space ( ), then loop through that, only appending the next part if it was under the character limit.

Is there a simpler method, like a function I don't know about, or would what I said above be the best way?

This is in **javascript** as well.

Comment: ***A possibility of achieving what I want would to be to split the string every space ( ), then loop through that, only appending the next part if it was under the character limit.***.  That's the way to do it.

Comment: A non-looping solution just occurred to me, answer updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Since you know the last character of each block will always be the same and will not occur elsewhere in the block you can solve this without looping by simply checking to see if the cut string ends with that character. If it doesn't then split into an array, remove the last element and rejoin the remaining elements to return your properly cut string.

```
let trimmed = src.substring(0,limit).trimEnd();

trimmed = trimmed.endsWith('>') ? trimmed : trimmed.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
```

```js
const src = '<@756307474931515432> <@123891849950781999> <@935718581892734987> <@589058297589273488>';

const limit = 54;

// Cut string to desired length and trim white space in case 
// it cut right after a space
let trimmed = src.substring(0,limit).trimEnd();

// If the string ends with '>' then you are done
// else split the string, slice off the last element, and rejoin
trimmed = trimmed.endsWith('>') ? trimmed : trimmed.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');

console.log(trimmed);
```

In cases where the last character of each block is not known or is not differentiated from the rest of the block, you will need to use iteration either over an array generated from the string or over the string itself.

**Looping solutions**

Splitting and looping/reducing seems straight forward. But to avoid looping unnecessary groups past the limit you could call `substring()` first.

```
const limit = 54;
const trimmed = src.substring(0,limit);
```

Since this returns a string of exactly the limit length it requires that you use `<` rather than '<=' in the reduce function to avoid it rebuilding and returning the entire incorrectly cut string. Using `<` rather `<=` also accounts for the space that gets added back in should the groups add up to the limit exactly.

```js
const src = '<@756307474931515432> <@123891849950781999> <@935718581892734987> <@589058297589273488>';

const limit = 54;

const trimmed = src.substring(0,limit).split(' ').reduce((acc, s) => { 
  if (acc.length + s.length < limit) return acc + ' ' + s;
  return acc;
  }, '');

console.log(trimmed);
```

Another curious solution is to find the index of the last space before the limit using `indexOf`

```js
const input = '<@756307474931515432> <@123891849950781999> <@935718581892734987> <@589058297589273488>';
const limit = 54;

let cut;
let i = -1;
while (i <= limit) {
  i = input.indexOf(' ', i+1);
  if (i <= limit) cut = i;
};

const output = input.substring(0, cut);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some function like this.

```
const src = '<@756307474931515432> <@123891849950781999> <@935718581892734987> <@589058297589273488>';
const limit = 54;

const limitText = src.substring(0,limit);
const subStr    = limitText.split(' ');
const finalString = subStr.reduce((res, s) => { 
      if (res.length + s.length < limit) {
        return res + ' ' + s;
      }
  return res;
  }, '');

console.log(finalString);
```